# Swift: spritenode is still dynamic during collision even after setting dynamic to false?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Alright, so my sprite node `savior` needs to be static so that when it collides with my other node `chicken1`, it doesn't get flipped upside down or onto its side. It needs to stay right side up.

I set up `savior` here:

```
var saviorTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "1.png")
        saviorTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

        savior = SKSpriteNode(texture: saviorTexture)
        savior.setScale(0.2)
        savior.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.5, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.2)
//Savior physics

    savior.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    savior.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    savior.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    savior.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(savior.size.width, savior.size.height))

    savior.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Savior.toRaw()
    savior.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Chicken1.toRaw()
    savior.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Chicken1.toRaw()


    self.addChild(savior)
```

As you can see, I have `allowsRotation` set to false and `dynamic` set to false, and yet rotation is still being allowed and the node is still dynamic.

Also When I turn on viewing the physics bodies, my 2 other static nodes have green physics bodies while `savior` has a dark blue physics body, leading me to believe that green is for static and blue is for dynamic. That makes `savior` definitely dynamic.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting physics body properties before you are actually declaring one. First declare it like you already do

```
savior.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(savior.size.width, savior.size.height))
```

then set all the properties.